# Children of child node not visible

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hopefully this is a pretty simple question. I simply have a `GameScene` (a `CCNode`) and then I have another `CCNode` named `Level1`. `Level1` has a `CCPhysicsNode` as a child of it, and then there are multiple bodies that are children of the `CCPhysicsNode`.

I want to be able to make several levels and then add them as a child to my `GameScene`. This works perfectly fine if I add a sprite directly to my `Level1` node, it shows up and everything. But as soon as I add my sprite as a `CCPhysicsNode`, which is a child of `Level1`, the sprites no longer show up. I can verify with code that the `CCPhysicsNode` still has the sprites attached to it by doing

```
int numberChildren = [[level.physicsNodeLevel1 children] count];
    CCLOG(@"number of children on node of level1: %i", numberChildren);
```

and I get the proper amount. So it seems that everything is working perfectly fine except for my physics bodies under the `CCPhysicsNode` are not showing up on the screen. How could I fix this? Thanks =)

**FURTHER DETAILS**

I'm using spritebuilder to create my levels. I have a .ccbi file named `GameScene` and then there is a node attached to it named `_levelNode`. I then have another .ccbi file named `Level1`. In my code I add `Level1` to `_levelNode`. Inside of `Level1` I have a `CCPhysicsNode` and then all of the sprites under that.

The important part of the code is then

```
if (curLevel.levelNum == 1) {
   level = (Level1*)[CCBReader load:@"Levels/Level1"];
   [_levelNode addChild:level];
}
```

which of course, causes the sprites added to the `CCPhysicsNode` in spritebuilder to not be on my screen.

Comment: Just for confirmation, have you applied any gravity so that object(dynamic body) affected by gravity and going off the screen ??

Comment: Alok, thanks that was it!!! haha